# Как работать с вложенным словарем C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> status = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
int count = 0;
int[] li = new int[] { 6, 77, 25, 18 }; //загружаемые из БД словари
foreach (int a in li)
{
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand($"select code,name from dict where parent_id={a}");
    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("СТРОКА ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ БД"))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            //status.Add(count, status[count].Add(1,"2"));
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

Загружаю 4 словаря и распихиваю их в status.
Я вижу это так:

```
{
 {
  0,
    {
     {1,"фраза"},
     {2,"фраза"}
    },
 {
  1,
    {
     {1,"фраза"},
     {2,"фраза"}
    }
}
```

Как правильно реализовать метод Add при такой структуре?
Как получить значение без использования цикла? К примеру мне необходимо получить значение из 1 словаря 2 фразу. Гугл молчит и не дает результатов.

Comment: почему просто не использовать индексацию? Словарь[1][2]

Comment: В данный момент остановился на примере из гугла.
status.Add(count, status[count].Add(1, "2"));

Пример брал здесь и слегка адаптировал
https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2030915.html

однако работать не хочет

Comment: проверил в онлайн компиляторе, пример по ссылке - всё работает прекрасно, может дело в том что C# 6.0?

Comment: Вопрос решён? Если да, опубликуйте ответ. Если нет, отредактируйте его, уточнив проблему.

Comment: Не используйте конкатенацию строк для sql-запроса! Используйте параметры!

Comment: Зачем вы используете и `ExecuteNonQuery` и `ExecuteReader`?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, этот код даст желаемый результат.

```
var status = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
int[] li = new int[] { 6, 77, 25, 18 };

using (var command = new OdbcCommand("select code,name from dict where parent_id=?"))
using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(_connectionString))
{
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();

    var idParam = command.Parameters.Add("id", OdbcType.Int);

    for (int i = 0; i < li.Length; i++)
    {
        idParam.Value = li[i];

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            status.Add(i, dict);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var code = (int)reader["code"];
                var name = (string)reader["name"];

                dict.Add(code, name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вы совершенно правильно обернули в `using` типы Connection и Reader. Но и Command нужно использовать аналогично.

Всегда используйте параметризованные запросы: это защитит от sql-инъекций и увеличит производительность.

Поле `parent_id` скорее всего имеет тип `int`. Если это не так, укажите правильный тип вместо `OdbcType.Int`.

При получении `code` и `name` из ридера тоже укажите правильные типы, если я их не угадал.
Можете использовать `reader.GetInt32` и `reader.GetString`.